# Integrate $ \int {1\over x^2(x-1)^3} \, dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

How do you integrate $$ \int {1\over x^2(x-1)^3} \, dx  $$

I'd love some general advice on how to approach problems like these. I tried partial fraction expansion, but in the end it got me nowhere.

Let me clarify: This is where partial fraction expansion got me:

$$ \int {3\over (x-1)} \, dx - \int {2\over(x-1)^2} \, dx + \int {2\over(x-1)^3} \, dx - \int {3x-1\over x^2} \, dx $$

Problem is I still don't know how to integrate second and third fraction. And I feel I probably messed up somewhere along the road.

Comment: Hint: Make the substitution $u =x - 1$ for the last integrals when needed.

Comment: @Alizter perfect, I totally forgot about u-sub!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using partial fractions, you'll find

$$\frac{1}{x^2(x-1)^3} = -\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{3}{x} + \frac{3}{x-1} - \frac{2}{(x-1)^2} + \frac{1}{(x-1)^3}.$$

**EDIT:** To integrate the fractions in your original post you claim to have trouble with, remember that

$$\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)' = - \frac{1}{x^2} \text{ and } \left(\frac{1}{x^2} \right)' = - \frac{2}{x^3}.$$

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo. I meant the second and third! But thank you very much, seems like I need to use u-sub for the seoncd and third fractions.

Comment: @user1904218: You don't actually (explicitly) need substitution, you can use the chain rule which gives $((x-1)^{-1})' = -(x-1)^{-2}$ immediately.

Answer (score 1):

hint: use that $$\frac{1}{x^2(x-1)^3}=3\, \left( x-1 \right) ^{-1}-{x}^{-2}+ \left( x-1 \right) ^{-3}-2\,
 \left( x-1 \right) ^{-2}-3\,{x}^{-1}
$$